# Convert address to lat/lon in angular-google-maps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to get my feet on solid ground so if this is really easy forgive me for being a n00b.

I want to use angular-google-maps and I have the address at the client (don't have lat and lon stored currently) and would like to display a map of the address. It looks very simple when I have the lat and lon:

```
angular.module('myApplicationModule', ['google-maps']);

$scope.map = {
   center: {
    latitude: 45,
    longitude: -73
   },
   zoom: 8
};

//html
<google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom"></google-map>
```

so i am just missing the step of converting the address to lat and lon, thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert from a plain address (I assume this isn't a Google Maps location object you're dealing with here, but just a plain string address) to a latitude/longitude, you'll need to use the [Google geocoding library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/). This will return an object with a `geometry` property - this will contain your latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [directive](http://rashimuddin.wordpress.com/2014/08/12/google-maps-for-angularjs/) that takes an address and display on the map.